# Ошибка при установке приложения через ADB

Tags: java, android, adb, android-adb

При попытке установить приложение (любое) на устройство Haier Power P11 (является «устройством для тестирования». Характеристики: ARM64 MT6739, Android 8.1, root: Magisk) возникает ошибка: `Can’t find service: package`.

Ошибка возникала при: установке стороннего приложения (adbd Insecure) (с самого телефона установился без каких либо проблем), сборке приложения в Android Studio, сборке приложения на Flutter, React Native, Ionic Framework.

При исполнении команды `adb shell service list` получал пустой список сервисов, хотя через терминал на самом устройстве присутствует полный список всех сервисов.

В чем может быть проблема? Если требуется предоставить какие либо скриншоты, выполнения команд - сделаю.